# C while(condition); without instructions in body

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm studying C, and I've a doubt regarding while. In an exercise I've:

```
while(1){
   while((sockacc = accept(ds_sock,&client,&length)) == -1);

   --other instructions--
}
```

Can anyone tell me which is the function of the second while? I mean, I know what the accept call is used for. I don't understand why use a while condition if there isn't anything in the body.

Comment: The function being invoked could have side effects.  So execute it until ...

Comment: I think `accept(ds_sock,&client,&length)` is the answer you want. It looks like in this implementation that it returns -1 or 1 perhaps. There is an assignment here too: `sockacc = accept(ds_sock,&client,&length)`, where `sockacc` is likely used later in the "other instructions" section.

Comment: @JustinC I've edited the question. I know what the accept call is used for. I'd like to know why to use a while cicle without any instruction in the body of the while..

Comment: Because the authors decision is to retry the `accept()` ad-infinitum so long as it returns -1. There is no code block because the author has chosen the only course of action already: call `accept()` again. A poor model for error recovery if there ever was one, but that appears to be the decision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could rewrite this whole code as:

```
while(1){
    do {
        sockacc = accept(ds_sock,&client,&length);
    } 
    while(sockacc == -1);

   --other instructions--
}
```

The part in the while statement is just executed every loop iteration, and itself determines if the loop terminates.

Comment: so, in every situation, a while(function-condition) without instructions in body is the same as do{function-condition}while(..)?

Comment: @daimpa no, there is more than a condition in your code, there is a variable assignement, too. Notice how only the first part, which has a side-effect, has been put into the body, for clarity. The actual test remains in the while condition.

Comment: It does not matter if the while loop has a body or not, the behaviour is exactly the same: The conditional statement is evaluated (and hence `sockacc = accept(...)` is called) and if it's true the loop body is executed (if there is none nothing is done). Then the conditional statement is evaluated again (`sockacc = accept(...)` is called again) and then ... I think you got the point.

Comment: @daimpa - short answer is yes. in your post there was an instruction but the author chose to do the instruction `set the value of sockacc to the return value of accept()` within the condition. If that wasn't allowed the author would've made a body to do what @Marius has just suggested.

Answer (score 5):

Take a step back. Remember that the meaning of

```
while(c) s;
```

is just a short way of writing:

```
CONTINUE: 
if (c) 
  goto BODY;  
else 
  goto BREAK;
BODY: 
s;
goto CONTINUE;
BREAK: ;
```

and of course `break;` and `continue;` are `goto BREAK;` and `goto CONTINUE;`.  Loops aren't magical; they're just a short and pleasant way of writing a bunch of `goto` statements.

So your program:

```
while(1){
  while((sockacc = accept(ds_sock,&client,&length)) == -1);
  --other instructions--
}
```

is just a nicer way to write:

```
OUTER_CONTINUE: 
if (1) 
  goto OUTER_BODY;  
else 
  goto OUTER_BREAK;
OUTER_BODY: 
{
  INNER_CONTINUE: 
  if ((sockacc = accept(ds_sock,&client,&length)) == -1) 
    goto INNER_BODY;  
  else 
    goto INNER_BREAK;
  INNER_BODY: 
  ;
  goto INNER_CONTINUE;
  INNER_BREAK: ;
  --other instructions--
}
goto OUTER_CONTINUE;
OUTER_BREAK: ;
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons why `accept()` can return a failure (-1) is EINTR (interrupted system call).  The inner loop in this code retries `accept()` if it returns an error EINTR, or indeed any other error since it does not test the value of `errno` in the inner loop body.  This could be a performance problem if the error is EBADF (bad file descriptor, indicating that socket file descriptor either isn't a socket file descriptor or has somehow been destroyed).  Normally, you see a test in the body of the loop to ensure that the error is one of the limited set that the code expects.

Comment: Unfortunately daimpa didn't ask for the mechanics of `accept()`.

Comment: But he did ask about why the inner while loop is present, and my answer explains why it is present.